# How do I remove quotes from the column headers in a flat file with SSIS?

Tags: ssis

I've got a CSV file where all column headers and values are wrapped in quotes (`"`). In the Flat File Connection Manager Editor I've specified `"` in the Text qualifier field. That takes care of all the quotes around data values but it doesn't seem to affect the quotes around the column headers. Is there a way to strip the quotes from the column headers as well?

Answer (score 1):

If it's a source, then the column names are unfortunately "Col1". The other option would be to uncheck file has a header row and skip 1 row in the flat file connection manager. Then you'd be able to rename the columns as you desire.

As I think about this, you might be able to manually change the column names in the Flat File Connection Manager to remote the double quotes. And I guess there's also an option to define the column name in the Flat File Source within your data flow so the FFCM would specify it's `"Col1"` and you can map it to a friendlier name like `Column1`

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your csv file into a text file and then load that one. After you load the file, in the Text Qualifier put "
this should take care of both the double quotes around your header and your column values.